# why is my counter applying lazy effects vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

so I have a counter like this

```
<button class="btn btn-light" @click="incrementQuantity(order)">+</button>
    <td class="tg-lqy6">{{ order.quantity }}</td>
<button class="btn btn-light" @click="decrementQuantity(order)">-</button>
```

and those two buttons are supposed to increment and decrement this qunatity value
those are my methods :

```
 incrementQuantity(order){
        order.quantity += 1;
     
    },
    decrementQuantity(order){
        order.quantity -= 1;
    }
```

at first I thought it wasn't working but when I go to anyother component via router-link or sth and comeback the action is fired and it increments or decrements according to the number of clicks as long as I didn't reload the page "running on local host"
no errors in the console

please note: order comes from v-for ="order in orders" and I have added a key and orders the arrays is a prop from the App.vue parent  component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's how I solved it thanks to the help of Tzahi Leh

```
incrementQuantity(order) {
      this.$set(order, order.quantity, (order.quantity += 1));
    },
    decrementQuantity(order) {
      this.$set(order, order.quantity, (order.quantity -= 1));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I misunderstood your question, I think your problem is a known caveat of [reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html);
It happens when you update a nested value, and Vue has no way to know about it.

One way to fix it would be using `Vue.set / this.$set` as follows:

```js
incrementQuantity(order){
  this.$set(order, "quantity", order.quantity += 1);
},
decrementQuantity(order){
  this.$set(order, "quantity", order.quantity -= 1);
}
```

By the way, Vue 3 claims to fix this caveat -
You can learn more about it [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#reactivity-in-depth)

Comment: I'm still using vue 2, I copied your code instead of mine but same issue

Comment: very helpfull though I did this and it worked now:                                               this.$set(order, order.quantity, (order.quantity += 1));

Comment: Well, it already depends on how your data is structured but that's the general idea. I'm glad you figured it out

Comment: thank you very much this was my first time to encounter Vue.set, very helpful of you sir